# Why does a convergent sequence of test functions have to be supported in a single compact set?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I've often seen it repeated that for any convergent sequence of test functions $\phi_i$ in $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$, there must exist a compact set $K$ such that for all $i$, the support of $\phi_i$ is in $K$. I'm having trouble proving this, and in fact it seems false to me.

Let $K_n$ be an increasing sequence of compact sets whose union is $\Omega$, then define $\phi_i$ to be some smooth function which is zero on $K_i$, but has a little bump of height $1$ somewhere in $\Omega\backslash K_i$. Does this sequence not converge to $0$ in the test function topology?

Comment: That the test functions must be supported in the same compact set is the *definition* of the test function (pseudo)topology.  You can certainly come up with a sequence of test functions that fails this condition.  So, I am not sure what it is you are trying to disprove or prove.

Comment: @user8960 I thought the test function topology was the one induced by the semi-norms $||\cdot||_{K_n, N}$, the supremum of the at-most-N'th order partial derivatives of $\phi$ on the compact $K_n$.

Comment: You can drop this condition whenever you consider a compactly supported (set of) distributions. But if your distribution isn't, it can grow very fast as $x \to \infty$, so dropping the compact condition will be obviously a problem when trying to bound $\langle T,\varphi_n \rangle$. And note that in the context of tempered distributions, we replace the compact set condition by a growth rate condition and everything works well.

Comment: Start by proving that for any sequence of test functions such that $\bigcup_n supp(\varphi_n) = \mathbb{R}$ there exists a distribution $T$ such that $\langle T,\varphi_n \rangle $ diverges

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Test_function_space

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965573/seminorm-on-set-of-smooth-functions , for reference see: "A First Course in Sobolev Spaces" by G.Leoni. Also "Functional Analysis" by Rudin. Then, to see these things, the suggestions of @user1952009 seem fine.

Answer (score 5):

The topology induced by the seminorms $|| . ||_{K_n,N}$ is the topology f uniform convergence on compact sets (with all its derivatives). The "commonly-used" topology on the space f test functions is strictly finer.

A distribution is continuous with respect to the topology induced by the seminorms if (and only if!) the distribution has compact support.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\Omega := \mathbb{R}$ and
$$
\phi_k(x) := \begin{cases}
C_k \cdot \exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2 - k^2}\right), & \text{if } |x|< k, \\
0, &\text{elsewhere,}
\end{cases}
\qquad \text{where } \frac{1}{C_k} := \int_{-k}^{k} \phi_k(x) dx.
$$
Then, $\phi_k \in \mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\text{supp}(\phi_k) \subset [-k, k]$, but we can't find a compact interval $K$ so that $\text{supp}(\phi_k) \subset K$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
And we observe
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi_k(x) dx
= 1
\neq 0
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lim_{k \to \infty} \phi_k(x) dx.
$$